# Ruby: how to check how many parameters a block accepts?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to set up a method that takes a block as a parameter. I know you do this by giving the last parameter an & prefix, but once it's been passed, how should I verify it?

If I want to verify that an argument is a string, I could use `is_a?(String)`, for example.  But how do I verify that I have received a block that accepts one parameter? Or 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`Proc#arity`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Proc/arity) method to check how many arguments the block accepts:

```
def foo(&block)
  puts block.arity
end

foo { }        # => 0
foo { |a| }    # => 1
foo { |a, b| } # => 2
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the number of arguments that would not be ignored. If the
> block is declared to take no arguments, returns 0. If the block is
> known to take exactly n arguments, returns n. If the block has
> optional arguments, return -n-1, where n is the number of mandatory
> arguments. A proc with no argument declarations is the same a block
> declaring || as its arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Blocks aren't objects, so you can't do anything useful with them (except `yield` to them, of course).

I mean, there's no way to refer to them, they aren't even bound to a name:

```
def foo
  yield 'foo'
end

foo do |bar| puts bar end
# foo
```

Inside `foo`, the block isn't bound to any variable, you cannot even refer to it, so you obviously cannot query it about its parameters either.

You *can* however ask Ruby to convert the block to a `Proc` and bind it to a parameter. Then, you can refer to it by name, *and* you have the full `Proc` API at your disposal, including `Proc#parameters`:

```
def foo(&blk)
  blk.parameters
end

foo do |m1, m2, o1=:o1, o2=:o2, *splat, m3, m4, 
      ok1: :ok1, mk1:, mk2:, ok2: :ok2, **ksplat, &blk| end
# => [[:opt, :m1],
#     [:opt, :m2],
#     [:opt, :o1],
#     [:opt, :o2],
#     [:rest, :splat],
#     [:opt, :m3],
#     [:opt, :m4],
#     [:keyreq, :mk1],
#     [:keyreq, :mk2],
#     [:key, :ok1],
#     [:key, :ok2],
#     [:keyrest, :ksplat],
#     [:block, :blk]]
```

However, note that the idea of "arity of a block" is a hairy concept in Ruby, because of the loose parameter binding semantics of blocks. Parameter binding semantics of blocks are different than the parameter binding semantics of methods, in particular when it comes to arity:

- If the block only takes a single parameter, but multiple arguments are passed, that's not an error, instead the arguments are passed as a single `Array` bound to the parameter (as if the parameter had been declared as a `*splat` parameter).
- If the block takes multiple parameters, but only a single argument is passed, that argument is converted to an `Array` and its individual elements are passed as arguments instead (as if they had been passed as a `*splat` argument).
- If more arguments are passed than the block takes parameters, the extra arguments are ignored.
- If fewer arguments are passed than the block takes parameters, the extra parameters are bound to `nil`.

All in all, the semantics are closer to that of assignments than method calls.

For example, you will note that even though `m1` and `m2` are declared as mandatory positional parameters in the block, `Proc#parameters` lists their type as `:opt`, i.e. optional parameters.

In other words: even a block that declares only one parameter still takes two arguments, and a block that declares two parameters can be invoked with just one argument.

One example where this is useful: the entire `Enumerable` mixin is based on methods that `yield` a *single* element. However, for `Hash`, you *really* want to deal with *two* arguments, `key, value`. And you *can*, because `Hash#each` `yield`s an `Array` of two elements, and a block that declares two parameters but only receives one argument will "splat" that argument across its parameters, so that you end up with the key bound to `key` and the value bound to `value` without having to copy&paste two-argument versions of all of `Enumerable`s methods.

Comment: Note: mandatory arguments after optional arguments are new in 1.9, keyword arguments are new in 2.0, mandatory keyword arguments are new in 2.1. You'll get a `SyntaxError` otherwise. I just wanted to demonstrate the full power of `Proc#parameters` (and the ever-growing uselessness of `Proc#arity` in the presence of keyword arguments.)